# Explorer.exe COMRuntime error: unexisting user can't get access permissions to COM server

Tags: windows-7, permissions, windows-explorer, acl, com

since explorer has no appid, it's not possible to find relevant DCOM component in *Component Services*. I tried editing access rights in *Elevated-Unelevated Explorer Factory* component and editing permissions in explorer.exe file directly, but there is no *nt authority/local service* **user** - only *local service* **group**, adding it to the access list and giving it privileges doesn't fix the event's occurrence. Explorer starts normally, with random Logon SID at startup. Still I wanna fix that popping error.

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110292940/explorer.png]

Answer (score 0):

The user **S-1-15-19** is the **LOCAL_SERVICE**. My error have disappeared (so far) following these steps:

1. Start **dcomcnfg** and navigate to My Computer.
2. Right click on **My Computer** and select **Properties**
3. Select **COM Security** tab.
4. In **Launch and Activation Permission**, click **Edit Default**
5. Click **Add**
6. In **Select Users or Groups**, click **Advanced**.
7. In **Advanced** (actually, the name of the panel is still **Select Users or Groups**), click **Find Now**
8. Scroll down and select LOCAL_SERVICE
9. Give **Local Activation** and **Local Right** to LOCAL_SERVICE
10. Do the same (#5-8) for **Edit Limits** and also **Access Permission Edit Limits** and **Edit Default**.

***NOTE: My OS is Win 8.1***

Comment: I have already done that, but in my case it didn't help. I managed to remove the error by resetting ACL system-wide with this utility: http://asilaydyingdl.deviantart.com/art/ACL-repair-utility-for-Vista-7-182330082